# change color table row if button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of the table row when the button is clicked. but I have a problem with the code. when I click the button, the color of the table row does not change.

**CSS**:

```
tr.highlighted td {
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
Change
</button>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$('#data tr').click(function(e) {
        $('#change').click(function() {
        $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    })
});
```

Comment: do you want row to be highlighted on row click. or you want to first click row and then click btn to highlight it?

Comment: because the answers down here are for later scenarios

Comment: i want to first click row and then click btn to highlight row. thank's for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

**Demo 2** and **Demo 3** added. One of the demos behaves as the OP commented hopefully.

- **Demo 2:** The `<tr>` are selected by click then highlighted by clicking the button.
- **Demo 3:** Same as **Demo 2** except only one row can be highlighted at a time.

---

Delegate the click event on document object. Any click to the document (which is basically the whole page) will be detected -- this of course is not desirable.

```
`$(document).on("click',...`
```

Delegating what actually reacts to the click and what doesn't is the goal of the programming pattern called Event Delegation. jQuery provides an optional second parameter referred to as a `data` object in any event method signature. This parameter is basically a selector string that specifies the scope of `$(this)`:

```
`$(document).on("click', '#data td, #change', ...
```

So the example above delegates the click event exclusively to any `<td>` within `#data` ***OR*** `#change`. Clicks anywhere other than to the delegated elements is ignored (unless there's another click event handler down the line). The last parameter is the callback function that will be invoked when triggered by a click event on any `<td>` of `#data` or `#change`. The callback function uses `$(this)` and flow controls to delegate the click event and determine behavior (or outcome).  In the demo it is basically `.toggleClass()` method that `.addClass()` to target `<tr>(s)` without the `.highlighted` class and inversely `.removeClass()` to target `<tr>(s)` that already has the `.highlighted` class.

Further details commented in demo.

Click any `<td>` directly and its parent `<tr>` class `.highlighted` is toggled.

Click the button and all `.highlighted` classes on all `<tr>` are toggled.

#### Demo 1

**Click either the `<tr>` or button to highlight `<tr>`**

```js
/*
Delegate click event on document -- 
Consider clicks only on #data td or #change
*/
/*
if the clicked tag is a <td>...
get the .closest <tr> from that <td> and add .highlighted 
class if it doesn't have it otherwise remove .highlighted
*/
/*
...otherwise get all <tr> and toggle the .highlighted class
*/
$(document).on('click', '#data td, #change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('td')) {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlighted');
  } else {
    $('#data tr').toggleClass('highlighted');
  }
});
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
Change
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Demo 2

**Click `<tr>` to select/deselect then click button to highlight all selected `<tr>`.**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#data td, #change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('td')) {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
  } else {
    $('#data tr:not(.selected)').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('#data tr.selected').addClass('highlighted');
  }
});
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
Change
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Demo 3

**The last `<tr>` clicked is selected and then highlighted when button is clicked**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#data td, #change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('td')) {
    $('#data tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('.selected').addClass('highlighted');
  }
});
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
Change
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome, @AlulR If this answer resolves the issue, don't forget to click the checkmark to accept it.✅

Comment: How would I do this if I wanted to select 1 as the maximum but not click a button to confirm it?

Comment: Mutually exclusive, like how a group of radio buttons behave -- only one can be selected at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The nested `click` handler have no sense here. Instead you can add a particular class, lets call it `active` to the last clicked `row` to keep track of it. After that, when you click the `change` button, you can first remove the `highlighted` class from every `row` and then add it to the `row` that hold the `active` class:

```js
$('#data tr').click(function(e)
{
    $('#data tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#change').click(function()
{
    $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $("tr.active").addClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: @AlulR You're welcome. Consider choosing an answer as accepted when you got the time. Also, you can up-vote useful answer when you get enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const $dataTr = $('#data tr');
const $change = $('#change');
let $toBeChanged = null;

$dataTr.click(function() {
  $toBeChanged = $(this);
  $change.prop('disabled', false);
});

$change.click(function() {
  $dataTr.removeClass('highlighted');
  $toBeChanged.addClass('highlighted');
})
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change" disabled>
Change
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in `$(this).addClass('highlighted');` refers to the button, not the table row, since `this` will be set to whatever raised to event to trigger the callback function to execute, in this case, the element with the id `change`. One of the easiest ways to fix this would be to assign `this` to another variable before you do `$('#change').click(function() {...})`.

Otherwise, if you want to make sure that only one table row is being changed at a time, you should separate the `('#data tr').click(function(e) {...})` and `$('#change').click(function() {...})` so that they are not nested, have a variable outside both that keeps track of which row was last clicked, and read that variable whenever `$('#change').click()` is raised (instead of capturing which table row was clicked when you register the callback).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` and `eq` method of jquery. Remove the nested `click`. First on click of the table `row` get the index of the row in the table using [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/). The value start from `0`. Set this value to a variable. Then use on click of the button use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the table row and add class to it

```js
let getRowIndex;
let elem = $('#data tr');
elem.click(function(e) {
  getRowIndex = $(this).index()
});

$('#change').click(function() {
  if (getRowIndex !== undefined) {
    elem.removeClass('highlighted');
    elem.eq(getRowIndex).addClass('highlighted');
  }
})
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
    Change
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#data tr').click(function(e) {
   if($(this).attr("class") == 'highlighted'){
       $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
      }else{
       $(this).addClass('highlighted');
      }
});
})
```

```css
tr.highlighted td {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">
Change
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching `click` event to table tr's and then inside the callback function you are attaching a click event to your `button`. Within the button `click` callback your `$(this)` will refer to your button and not clicked tr. Instead add the classes to clicked `tr` itself.

```js
$('#data tr').click(function(e) {
    $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="change">Change</button>
```